# python: pointwise list sum

Tags: python, list

```
Input: two lists (list1, list2) of equal length
Output: one list (result) of the same length, such that:
    result[i] = list1[i] + list2[i]
```

Is there any concise way to do that? Or is this the best:

```
# Python 3
assert len(list1) == len(list2)
result = [list1[i] + list2[i] for i in range(len(list1))]
```

Comment: I originally read this as "pointless wise sum". I think I might need some sleep.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the builtin [zip](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/functions.html#zip) function, or you can also use do it mapping the two lists over the add operator. Like this:

```
from operator import add
map(add, list1,list2)
```

Comment: +1 Didn't know that `map` can accept several iterables. Definitely better than my answer :)

Answer (score 10):

IMO the nicest way is

```
result = [x + y for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

with Python3 basic `zip` is not even building an intermediate list (not an issue unless `list1` and `list2` lists are huge).

Note however that `zip` will stop at the shortest of the input lists, so your `assert` is still needed.

Answer (score 5):

```
[a + b for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways, e.g. using [**`map`**](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map), [**`sum`**](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) and [**`izip`**](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) (but afaik, `zip` works the same as `izip` in Python 3):

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> map(sum, izip(list1, list2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

```
result = [x+x for x,y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Comment: You mean `x + y`?

Answer (score 0):

using the + as pointwise sum is the default operation on numpy arrays.
the * operator likewise is the pointwise multiplikation:

```
import numpy as np
list1 = np.array(list1)
list2 = np.array(list2)
assert list(list1+list2) == list([list1[i] + list2[i] for i in range(len(list1))])
assert list(3*list1) == list([3*list1[i] for i in range(len(list1))])
```

comparing two list equal with == does not work with np arrays though.